# Some meta tag synonyms

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, meta

I propose that the tags below on the left be merged and possibly synonymized to those on the right. Because if there's one thing people love more than tags, it's tags on meta.<sup>1</sup>

- [statistics](/questions/tagged/statistics) → [site-statistics](/questions/tagged/site-statistics)
- <s>[css](/questions/tagged/css) → [design](/questions/tagged/design) possibly</s>
- [wrong-answers](/questions/tagged/wrong-answers) → [incorrect-answers](/questions/tagged/incorrect-answers)
- [edit](/questions/tagged/edit) → [editing](/questions/tagged/editing)
- [interesting-tags](/questions/tagged/interesting-tags) → [tags](/questions/tagged/tags): [interesting-tags](/questions/tagged/interesting-tags) is one of the [default tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233898/what-tags-exist-by-default-on-child-metas) that the cleanup script won't touch. No one uses it, but it might as well be a synonym of [tags](/questions/tagged/tags).
- [quotes](/questions/tagged/quotes) → [quotation](/questions/tagged/quotation)

---

<sup>1</sup> What, that's just me? <sub>*awkward*</sub>

Comment: No, it's not just you: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9633/retagging-retagging-or-a-tag-cleanup-tag-cleanup

Comment: Except one , all seems valid to me. Anyways Rand done is already but still +1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [statistics](/questions/tagged/statistics) → [site-statistics](/questions/tagged/site-statistics)

**Done.** There were only a few questions with each of these tags, and both seem to be used identically.

> [css](/questions/tagged/css) → [design](/questions/tagged/design) possibly. If these should not be synonyms, then the tag wiki excerpt for [design](/questions/tagged/design) could use some clarification.

I'll let someone else handle this one, since I don't know enough about website design to even know what CSS means.

> [wrong-answers](/questions/tagged/wrong-answers) → [incorrect-answers](/questions/tagged/incorrect-answers)

**Done.** These tags are clearly identical.

(And apparently both tags have only ever been used by one user. I get that incorrect but upvoted answers are a pet peeve of his, but it's a pity nobody else has ever seen fit to post to meta about this important site quality issue [unless they have but haven't used the tag].)

> [edit](/questions/tagged/edit) → [editing](/questions/tagged/editing)

**Done.** The first of these only has a few questions and is clearly synonymous to the second.

> [interesting-tags](/questions/tagged/interesting-tags) → [tags](/questions/tagged/tags): [interesting-tags](/questions/tagged/interesting-tags) is one of the [default tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233898/what-tags-exist-by-default-on-child-metas) that the cleanup script won't touch. No one uses it, but it might as well be a synonym of [tags](/questions/tagged/tags).

**Nah.** I'm not sure what [interesting-tags](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interesting-tags) is meant to be for, but if someone comes up with a distinct and sensible meaning for it, they're free to start asking questions with that tag. Let's not synonymise it before it's even been used.

> [quotes](/questions/tagged/quotes) → [quotation](/questions/tagged/quotation)

**Done (ish).** I did this merge the other way round, since even though there are more questions tagged [quotation](/questions/tagged/quotation) than [quotes](/questions/tagged/quotes), the latter seems like a more intuitive name for the tag: people ask questions about *quotes* in questions and answers here, not about famous *quotations*.

Comment: [This comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277616/which-tags-are-automatically-added-to-per-site-metas?lq=1#comment899404_277618) mentions [meta-tag:interesting-tags], but I still don’t know what its intended use was. I guess it doesn’t matter, since only one person has [ever used that tag](http://data.stackexchange.com/meta.scifi/query/486770), and you removed it.

Comment: @anaranjada Huh, I'd forgotten that. Guess I removed [meta-tag:interesting-tags] because it wasn't an interesting tag. Argh, this is getting too meta for me! Btw, watch out for the new meta question coming up ...

Comment: Wait, does “quote” as a noun mean something different from “quotation”?

Comment: @anaranjada They're kinda synonymous, but I'd say "quotation" sounds more high-brow than "quote". We can make *quotations* from Shakespeare or Byron, but only mention *quotes* from JK Rowling or George Lucas.

Comment: I just hit 2.5k and +5 score in [meta-tag:tags], but it says [meta-tag:interesting-tags] doesn’t exist when I try to suggest it as a synonym of [meta-tag:tags]. The universe is conspiring against me.

Comment: @anaranjada Maybe because [meta-tag:interesting-tags] doesn't actually have any questions?

Comment: @Randal'Thor HTML is the bare bones of a webpage, CSS is what is used to give it colour and shape and size. I suggest that 'css → design' is not synonymised, as it is possible for a question to be about the site's CSS, but not the site's design.